# Data/Object Consistency in noSQL database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, consistency

I got a question when I develop a pretty large project. Say I store an object in no-sql db, like Google Cloud Datastore, but then I add a new field to this class, then once I make a query and get this object, what will be the value of new field? Does it depend on the serializer or DB or programming language?
For example, in java:

```
public class Car{
   private int numOfDoors;
   public Car(int nod){
       numOfDoors = nod;
   }
}
```

Then I save an object car1 to Datastore, but I update my code after that.

```
public class Car{
    private int numOfDoors;
    private Set<String> tags;
    private boolean condition;
    public Car(int nod, Set<String> tags, boolean cod){
         numOfDoors = nod;
         this.tags = tags;
         condition = cod;
    }
    public Set<String> getTags(){
         return tags;
    }
}
```

What will happen if I call `getTags()` when I just update the code and call get to an object just fetched from Datastore?
What if tags and condition are not in contructor? Like:

```
private Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

What about delete a field?
Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the specific backend and the library/tools you're using to access it. Most often, you'll get the default values in your Java class.

Comment: *"Does it depend on the serializer or DB or programming language?"* - Potentially, all of them.  If you want a useful answer, you will need to be more specific.  However, there is one fundamental principle: There is no magic.  If something would seem to require a magical implementation, then it is probably not supported.

Comment: Read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema). It's about python, but it gives you an idea of what happens when you update your schema in Datastore

Answer (score 0):

In the [Defining Data Classes with JDO](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses) of the Google Cloud Documentation, specifically the Object [Fields and Entity Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Object_Fields_and_Entity_Properties) section, it is explained that:

> If a datastore entity is loaded into an object and doesn't have a
>   property for one of the object's fields and the field's type is a
>   nullable single-value type, the field is set to null. When the object
>   is saved back to the datastore, the null property becomes set in the
>   datastore to the null value. If the field is not of a nullable value
>   type, loading an entity without the corresponding property throws an
>   exception....

So basically the newly added properties in the modified class will be set to null because the saved entity doesn't have them.